# Unable to build apk or run the app

Tags: java, android, gradle

The gradle build completes successfully , but while running the application or trying to build the apk I am getting  an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [F:\TravEz\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\51b8cdc0bcfc98652d9ae95f70697b30\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

I have tried all the methods mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342094/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug)

Here is my project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    //Glomadrian maven for animated switch
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"}
    maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"}
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.travez.travez"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
//library for cardview
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
//library for dialog box
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
//library for animated switch
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//Firebase authentication library
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
//Firebase database library
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
//Google play services and maps libraries
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
//Geofire library
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.0'
//Runtime perission library
compile 'com.github.karanchuri:PermissionManager:0.1.0'
//Material Edit Text library
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
//Calligraphy library
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
// CircleView library
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.nbsp:library:1.8'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Is written twice, remove one of them.

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
```

Replace the + with the current version of the library

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have duplicated support library in your dependencies.

android-image-cropper is using support library 27+, you can check [its build.gradle](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/build.gradle). MaterialEditText is using [support library `22.2.0`](http://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/blob/master/library/build.gradle). Material Animated Switch is using [support library `22.2.0`](https://github.com/glomadrian/material-animated-switch/blob/master/materialanimatedswitch/build.gradle). You need to exlude the support libraries from them.

So, instead using the following:

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
```

use the following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'

implementation ('com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

implementation ('com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}

implementation ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

You can check the dependencies tree if you still found the conflicted libraries with:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```