# how do i fix the error duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.class?

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.class

dependencies {

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}

compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
```

can someone help me fix this error please.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). You shouldn't import ALL the Google Play Services. Idk if this is the issue, but at least like that you'll not need to activate multidex, so it should at least solve a couple of issues in the future

Comment: same with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342094/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfordebug ?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I got the same issue. I think I have fixed it by deleting `android-support-v4.jar` from the libs folder.

Comment: i deleted the file but when i rebuild my project i got this error                          **Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform file 'support-v4-19.0.1.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
   > Transform output file C:\Users\midox\Desktop\Pirate_Runner_Android\app\libs\support-v4-19.0.1.jar does not exist.**